How to re-use QGIS map layout for other projects /How to create a print layout template?
I have created a print layout for a QGIS project and would like to use that print layout as template for other projects. How can I make the template globally available in QGIS?
I had a look into the relevant tutorials but the print layouts were used only in one project.
I would need to be able, to save the templates and even import them into other instances of QGIS as colleagues need to be able to use them on their machines, too.
Is there a way to do that?
It would be great I the layouts could be available in the layout manager:


First you need to save the layout as a template (You may create a folder where you store all your template, you can place the folder in a shared location or share the folder with other. Here I use the "C:/My_QGIS_Layout_Template" folder as an exemple)

Then you need to add the Paths to your template folder in Options>Layouts (just click the + in the Layout Paths section and navigate to your folder to select it), if you store your template in several different folder add them all :

Then your template are available in the layout manager (template from all folder added in the previous step will be listed here in alphabetical order) in the "New from Template" section use the drop down list to select the template you want to use then click the create button.

To find a template from a folder not added in the Options>Layouts>Layout Paths
select "Specific" in the dropdown, this will activate the field below and let you navigate to your layout file...
